# Recursive directives in angular 5 Dynamic modules (without circular dependencies)

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to load dynamic templates into an angular 5 app.
First try was the examples in the angular docs, https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader This was a dead end because all it does is load static components dynamically.

Second up was a well informed blog post from the AngularInDepth.com Max NgWizard K
https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

This works like a charm to render templates dynamically. I have, however, hit a snag trying to wire my dynamic components to do recursive calls or even load common modules.

Looking around stackoverflow most of the answers are outdated with plunkers that are not working and the few that work don't really solve circular dependencies issue or even load modules apart from interpolations that is already working in my case.

I have forked an angular docs project to demonstrate the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aa3ah1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, Compiler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Portal } from './portal'
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() msg: any;
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;


  templates = [//interpolation works without a problem
                `<span> 
                  This works:  {{msg.comment}}
                </span>`,
                // How to import a directive in the template?
                `<span *ngFor="let comment of msg.childComments"> 
                  Directive :  {{comment.comment}}
                </span>`,
                // How to reuse the portal without circular dependancies???
                `<span> 
                  This does not work because app-heroes
                   is not accessible and importing module causes circular dependancies
                   {{msg.comment}}
                </span>
                <span *ngFor="let comment of msg.childComments">
                  <app-heroes [msg]="comment"></app-heroes>
                </span>

                `];

  constructor(private _compiler: Compiler) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTemplate(this.templates[0], this.msg, this.vc, this._compiler);
  }

  loadTemplate(myTemplate: string, data: any, vc: ViewContainerRef, compiler: Compiler){
    const portal = Component({template: myTemplate})(Portal);
    //const pModule = NgModule({declarations: [portal], imports: [HeroesComponent]})(class{});
    const pModule = NgModule({declarations: [portal], imports: [SharedModule]})(class{});

    compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(pModule)
        .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        const cmpRef = vc.createComponent(f);
        cmpRef.instance.msg = data;
    });
  }
}
```

1. How can i get the common modules to work in my dynamic components (template[1])?
2. How can i reuse the dynamic component to make recursive directives (template[2])?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i get the common modules to work in my dynamic components (template[1])?

CommonModule holds NgFor directive, so straightforward way is to import that module:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

//...

const pModule = NgModule({declarations: [portal], imports: [SharedModule, CommonModule]})(class{});
```

But I would probably create another module, import NgForOf from CommonModule, add it to declarations and export arrays. And later instead import that module, so no need to import whole library from CommonModule.

**Edit:**

Ok, I got your point. But still, you cant use `<parent-comp></parent-comp>` in its child, cause it would end up with infinite loop. Without much thinking about refactoring, I might follow this way:

Notify Portal.ts about the comment:

```
<span *ngFor="let comment of msg.childComments">
  <span msg="comment"></span>
</span>
// but note that msg will refer to the last item from ngFor
```

Check it if has any childComments and if it does, call HeroesComponent `loadTemplate()` method via an EventEmitter or a service.

Comment: Thank you very much .. you have the right answers sir ! The suggestion to import CommonModule in the SharedModule and export the ngForOf in the SharedModule works perfectly too!(upvote for that).

Comment: For the second issue, am trying to use the component as a loader of dynamic components and in some cases those dynamic templates should be able to load other dynamic templates. It seems like an infinite loop but with the right break cases like in the example the recursive loop ends eventually - eg. the 3rd template only calls the `HeroesComponent ` if the comment has `childComments`.